# Google SketchUp export dynamic component to .dae model options are missing?

Tags: sketchup

I have exported this model to dae:

http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/details?mid=c1e4befdfbfd283135b07d6213c348&prevstart=0

But when I import it, it says  `There are no options to choose on this component..`

Why are the options missing in the dae model? Are there any way to add these dynamic options?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: explode the imported Component, or open the model instead of importing it.

Not all Dynamic Components work this way - some are made to work correctly when imported. It depends on how the model author saved the DC.